# Removing empty strings

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have written the folllowing regex and would like to get empty strings removed automatically and could not find any equivalent to RemoveEmptyEntries for Regex which I found only for the Split method in string.

```
string test = "{ key1 = { key2= xx } | key3 = y | key4 = z }";
string[] help = Regex.Split(test, "(=)|({)|(})|(\\|)");
```

The result string array contains elements which are empty. I would like to run the regular expression without yielding any empty strings contained in the result.

I will run this code very, very frequently - thus I need it as efficient as possible.
Updates: As this is a parser I need to keep the tokens and I found only a way with Regex to keep them.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean with "to get empty strings removed automatically"? You want to remove spaces? It's not very clear (at least for me)

Comment: It's not clear to me either.  Can you post some before and after strings showing what input you have and what output you expect?

Comment: The result string array contains elements which are empty. I would like to run the regular expression without yielding any empty strings contained in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not a full solution to the question, but I have a few remarks for the problem at hand (tokenizing a string):

```
the original regex:    (=)|({)|(})|(\|)
is equivalent to:      (=|{|}|\|)
is equivalent to:      ([={}|])
```

All of the above expressions return the same 21 elements, but they perform differently. I set up a quick test going over 100,000 iterations of `Split()` operations using pre-built Regex objects with `RegexOptions.Compiled` and the `Stopwatch` class.

- regex #1 takes 2002ms on my hardware
- regex #2 takes 1691ms
- regex #3 takes 1542ms
- regex #4 takes 1839ms (that's the one below)

YMMV.

However, the desired elements can still be surrounded by white space. I figure this is undesired as well, so the regex I would split on would be this:

```
\s*([={}|])\s*
```

The returned elements are:

```
["", "{", "key1", "=", "", "{", "key2", "=", "xx", "}", "", "|", "key3", "=", "y", "|", "key4", "=", "z", "}", ""]
```

The few remaining empty strings should not pose a big problem performance-wise when iterating the array and can be taken care of (read: ignored) when they are encountered.

EDIT: If you measure performance it is possible that you find splitting on `([={}|])` and trimming the array elements "manually" is faster than splitting on `\s*([={}|])\s*`. Just try what works better for you.

Comment: As an additional note: considering there are still 4 empty strings after the split, my .Where() code is probably the best way to filter them out.

Comment: I get 21 elements also with the first regular expression, but I gain 4 ms on 1000 iterations when measuring the performance with StopWatch. I did not understand your last suggestion though - can you give me exact code - I get bad escape sequence.

Comment: Regular expressions and C# strings are two different things. You must escape backslashes in C# strings. I get back 51 elements when splitting on your original expression. I tried it with JavaScript regex though. Maybe there is a implementation difference between C# and JS in this regard?

Comment: I just tried it with C# and sure enough the Regex #1 returns 21 elements as well. I implemented a quick test in C#, I posted the results above.

Comment: The regular expressions are not equivalent if you want to use matches of the groups.

Comment: @Gumbo: They are used in Split() context. There is no using of the match groups.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that option is built into RegEx.  But with C#3.0 you could just use a simple `.Where()`:

```
string[] help = Regex.Split(test, "(=)|({)|(})|(\\|)")
                     .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
```

To make this more efficient, declare the RegEx once — perhaps at class level or make it static — rather than recreating it all the time.  Additionally, odds are you're only using the returned array to iterate over the results.  You can make this faster by skipping the `.ToArray()` call on the end and just keeping the IEnumerable for your iteration.

```
//earlier
RegEx KeySplitter = new RegEx ("(=)|({)|(})|(\\|)");
```

.

```
//later
string test = ""; // 
for (string key in KeySplitter.Split(test).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)))
{
    // ...
}
```

One of the nice things about how linq-to-objects works is that this will still only iterate over your `.Split` results *once*, because the `GetEnumerator` method in the `Where` function will do lazy evaluation.  Depending on what you need to do inside the for loop you might be able to gain a similar efficiency by adding a `.Select()` call.

Comment: Ok - this but this means that I add an additional LINQ query when doing the parsing. Not really nice - but at least I have not missed something trivial from the documentation.

Comment: Isn't "(=)|({)|(})|(\|)" a very complicated way of saying "[={}|]" in the first place? Or am I missing something fundamental here? The character class expression should be a lot faster.

Comment: And *if* the character class expression is what the OP is after, then there is String.Split(Char[]) to avoid regex altogether.

Comment: I need the keep the tokens for the parsing- thus I need the Regex or is there a way with the String class to keep the tokens?

Answer (score 1):

As for efficiency: If the stars are lucky, you can gain some performance by compiling the regex:

```
Regex r = new Regex ("<regex goes here>", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove spaces from a string just do this

```
Regex exp = new Regex(@"\s+");
string test = "{ key1 = { key2= xx } | key3 = y | key4 = z }";
string result = test.Replace(exp, string.Empty);
```

Or you could also do the following (did not test which one works faster)

```
Regex.Replace(test, " ", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Compiled)
```

Here is what Jeff Atwood (incidentally one of the creators of StackOverFlow has to [say about compiled regex](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000228.html) )

After this you can user your split code to put the keys into the string array.

Comment: To OP mentioned this is something that will happen over and over and over in quick succession, therefore compiled is the correct choice.

Comment: Better to show the door, than to carry them through the door!

Comment: I will change it to compiled, but my issue are the empty string elements in the result, not removing white spaces before...

Comment: The empty elements are in independently of removing white spaces before or not...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite figure out your question. But "^$" would mean a line that ends next to where it starts, therefore an empty line. Does that help?

Comment: I think he's looking for hte regex equivalent to StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries.

Comment: This is what I tried to say in my first line - sorry I am not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than splitting the string using the regex you could modify your regular expression and return a match collection. Something like this:

```
string test = "{ key1 = { key2= xx } | key3 = y | key4 = z }";

Regex regex = new Regex("[={}|]|[^\\s={}|]{1,}");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(test);

string[] help = new string[matches.Count];

for (int index = 0; index < matches.Count; index++)
{
    help[index] = matches[index].Value;                
}
```

This will return the same as your regular expression minus the empty (white space) elements in the final array.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I will try this possibility as well when benchmarking my parser with or without the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

So you want multiple occurrences of delimiters between values to be matched only once.

```
\s*[{}=|][\s{}=|]*
```

This should match, in this order, any amount of whitespace, one delimiter, and any amount of both whitespace and further delimiters.

Adding C# string escapes and a compilation declaration:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\\s*[{}=|][\\s{}=|]*");
```